# Close gnome-terminal with specific title from another script/shell command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to close a specific gnome-terminal window having a unique name from any other bash/shell script.

Eg:

```
$] gnome-terminal --title "myWindow123" -x "watch ls /tmp"

...
...
```

gnome-terminal opened in the name "myWindow123"

All I need is to kill that terminal from my script. Is there expect kind of script support in bash also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a contestant for the ugliest hack of the day:

```
sh$ TERMPID=$(ps -ef |
              grep gnome-terminal | grep myWindow123 |
              head -1 | awk '{ print $2 }')
sh$ kill $TERMPID
```

---

A probably better alternative would be to record the PID of the terminal at launch time, and then kill by that pid:

```
sh$ gnome-terminal --title "myWindow123" -x "watch ls /tmp"
sh$ echo $! > /path/to/my.term.pid

...
...
# Later, in a terminal far, far away
sh$ kill `cat /path/to/my.term.pid`
```

Comment: Can we have expect kind of script in bash also??

Comment: Neither of your solutions work, since the PID of `gnome-terminal` is different from that of the opened window.

Answer (score 0):

In the script that starts the terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal --title "myWindow123" --disable-factory -x watch ls /tmp &
echo ${!} > /var/tmp/myWindow123.pid
```

In the script that shall slay the terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /var/tmp/myWindow123.pid ]; then
  kill $(cat /var/tmp/myWindow123.pid && rm /var/tmp/myWindow123.pid)
fi
```

Comment: Added _--disable-factory_ argument to allow the script to run from a gnome-terminal.

Comment: `--disable-factory` is no longer supported, and this doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of an ugly hack, but you can create a wrapper script that takes a nonce as an argument, and then kill *that*.

```
cat > ~/wrapper.sh < 'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
#Throw away the nonce, and then run the command given
shift
"$@"
EOF
chmod +x ~/wrapper.sh
#Make a random string, so we can kill it later
nonce=`tr -dc '0-9A-Za-z' < /dev/urandom | head -n 10`
gnome-terminal -- ~/wrapper.sh "$nonce" watch ls /tmp
#...
#...
#...
#Kill any command with our nonce as one of its arguments
pkill -f "$nonce"
```